# How to use jacoco record which methods or lines are covered by each unit test case or api test case?

Tags: jacoco

I want to count which lines are covered by each use case of unit test or interface test。
For example, there are two test cases, test1 and test2. After I run these two test cases, I want to know which lines are covered by test1 and which lines are covered by test2.